# Intel WIFI firmware caused card to stop working

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, intel

I have an Intel AX201NGW bluetooth + WIFI card connected to my M2 slot on the motherboard. When I installed this, Ubuntu 20 detected the card fine and I got the connection dialog showing "Bluetooth" in the settings icon (which wasn't there before) and under Wi-fi showing me an Intel card. However, no WIFI networks or Bluetooth devices were in the lists to connect to.

On the advice of Intel I installed the firmware which I downloaded from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless.html) and installed with `sudo tar xvzf iwlwifi-qu-48.13675109.0.tgz -C /lib/firmware`. After rebooting, the WIFI card disappeared, and the bluetooth still does not work.

One possibly confounding issue is that I don't have an antenna connected to the card. Does anyone know if this should still work for Bluetooth without an antenna?

**UPDATE:**
After rebooting, the WIFI has now appeared again. Still can't see any networks or Bluetooth devices.

**UPDATE:** Some outputs for diagnostics:

```
systemctl | grep -i blue

  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d14-1\x2d14:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device                    loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                           loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                 
  bluetooth.service                                                                                     loaded active     running   Bluetooth service                                                     
  bluetooth.target                                                                                      loaded active     active    Bluetooth
```

```
dmesg | grep -i 'blue'  
[79058.990711] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000001bf61557 failed to resubmit (2)
[79078.082126] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 128 week 11 2020
[79088.211376] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (71)
```

```
lsusb              
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:7015 Qualcomm Atheros Communications TP-Link TL-WN821N v3 / TL-WN822N v2 802.11n [Atheros AR7010+AR9287]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:301d Dell Computer Corp. Dell Universal Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```